# Setting up WingIDE to debug Flask projects

Tags: python, flask, wing-ide

Has anyone had success setting up Flask project in WingIDE so that you can do breakpoint and use the debug probe on incoming requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you turn the Flask debugging off, it should allow for WingIDE's debugging to take over.  This works for Eclipse; unfortunately, I have no experience with WingIDE.  It's worth a shot at least.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = False
    app.run()
```

Comment: You're right, turning off flask's own debugging did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

https://wingware.com/doc/howtos/flask

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    if 'WINGDB_ACTIVE' in os.environ:
        app.debug = False
    app.run()
```